# Preferred value to encode 96 DPI within PNG

Tags: language-agnostic, png, dpi

PNG files may contain chunks of optional informations. One of these optional information blocks is the **physical resolution of the image** (chunk-signature **`pHYs`**).<sup>[1]</sup> <sup>[2]</sup> It contains separate values for horizontal and vertical resolution as *pixels per unit*, and a unit specifier, that can be `0` for unit unspecified, or `1` for *meter* ← *that's* quite confusing, because resolutions are traditionally expressed in **DPI**s.

[The Inch is defined as 25.4 mm in the metric system](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inch).
So, if I calculate this correctly, 96 DPIs means 3779.527559... dots per metre. For the `pHYs` chunk, this has to be rounded. I'd say **3780** is the right value, but I found also **3779** suggested on the web. Images of both kind also coexist on my machine.

The difference may not be important in most cases,

```
3779 * 0.054 = 95.9866
3780 * 0.054 = 96.012
```

but I try to avoid tricky layout problems when mixing images of both kind in processes that are DPI-aware like creating PDF files using LaTeX.

---

<sup>[1]</sup> [Portable Network Graphics (PNG) Specification (Second Edition), section11.3.5.3 pHYs Physical pixel dimensions](https://www.w3.org/TR/PNG/#11pHYs)

<sup>[2]</sup> [PNG Specification: Chunk Specifications, section 4.2.4.2. pHYs Physical pixel dimensions](http://www.libpng.org/pub/png/spec/1.2/PNG-Chunks.html#C.pHYs)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The relative difference is less that 0.03% (2.65/10000), it's hardly relevant.

Anyway, I'd go with 3780. Not only it's the nearest value, but it would give the correct value if some (sloppy) conversor rounds the value down (instead of rounding to the nearest).

Also, if you google "72.009 DPI PNG" you'll see a similar (non) issue with 72 DPI ([example](https://www.cocoanetics.com/2013/02/72-009-dpi/)), and it seems that most people rounded the value up (which is also the nearest) 2834.645 -> 2835

Comment: Thanks, I also like the rounded-up value more, because it's rounded correct. But sometimes there are conventions (like this of the TDateTime-to-Lotus-1-2-3 relationship) based on some historical reasons, and you are doing better to stick to them.